# c# S22 get sent emails

Tags: c#, .net, email, frameworks, imap

Hello i'm currently working on a CRM and i got my library written with S22 to access to my imap server of gmail. I can retrive the received emails and i can send emails using SMTP but i can't figure out on how to retrive the SENT ones.

The options i tried are the following:

- List all the folders and access to the "sent" one, then retrive the emails for that folder but all the ones i get are empty or null.
- Retrive all the emails with the "From" attribute with my address but none gets returned.

So i was wondering if there're some Searching criteria to access to the "SENT" emails.

Comment: You've pulled back the veil that email clients have been holding up for decades. SMTP doesn't save sent emails anywhere. Clients save a copy as a separate action from the sending process. If you're using SMTP, you have to save your own copy.

Comment: You have to upload it yourself using IMAP (using the ‘append’ function), except on certain email servers.  For example: gmail will automatically do this, but that’s nonstandard.

Comment: @madreflection I just didn't know that by the way i'm going to check if there's a way using c# to retrive the emails sent saved. Thanks